# Integral Numbers Question

Tags: integers

How many integer solutions are there to xyz=120? This is what I have tried so far: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=609981 see the first solution in this thread. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are your solutions to be positive integer solutions, or do you also allow negative integers? [From your statement, it should be both, but I was just wondering.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write that $120 = 2^3\times 5^1\times 3^1$. A decomposition $120 = abc$ implies

- $a = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}$
- $b = 2^{b_1}3^{b_2}5^{b_3}$
- $c = 2^{c_1}3^{c_2}5^{c_3}$ with $a_1 + b_1 + c_1 = 3$, $a_2 + b_2 + c_2 = 1$, 
  $a_3 + b_3 + c_3 = 1$.

As all choices are independent, you get

- 3 choices for the values of $(a_2, b_2, c_2)$ and $(a_3, b_3, c_3)$ 
  (which one is $\neq 0$)
- 10 choices for the value of $(a_1, b_1, c_1)$:

300;
210;
201;
120;
111;
102;
030;
021;
012;
003

hence a total of $3\times 3\times 10 = 90 $ choices.

---

if counting negative solutions as well, you should consider for each non negative solution
$a,b,c$ to the problem the solutions
$a, b, c$; 
$-a, -b, c$; 
$-a, b, -c$; 
$a, -b, -c$; so just multiply by 4 the total.